# How to create List Definition based on Wiki Page Library in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, list-definition, wiki-pages

While creating Wiki Page Library from the browser (**Site Actions->More Options->Wiki Page Library**) is easy, doing it form Visual Studio not so much.

When I create new ListDefinition in Visual Studio 2010 I use Custom Library or Document library.
Then in `elements.xml` of the `ListDefinition` I can edit `DocumentTemplate` (from default for Document Library `101` to `119` for the Wiki Page Library type) but it changes nothing and library stil behaves as normal document library. 
Is there something more to edit or do I have to generate this library from code?

I want to define my own columns so this is why I need to create ListDefinition. 
Because if you create new `ListInstance` you can choose Wiki Pages Library but then you have only `Elements.xml` in your Visual Studio 2010 project and can not add custom columns from there (only from SharePoint Designer).

Comment: Here is workaround, create documents library using visual studio, add all the content types of wiki page library  to the list definition of documents library

Comment: Don't create `List Definition` at all. It's an outdated approach - causes a lot of pain in maintenance. I recommend to create a custom `Content Type` for your columns. Then you create desired regular Wiki list(s) and add this `CT` into it (them).

Comment: @dbardakov - the problem is when you create list from `wiki page library` template in visual studio, you don't have access to `columns` tab, so you cant add custom type to wiki library :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to change the feature id as well?
From onet.xml:

```
<List FeatureId="00BFEA71-C796-4402-9F2F-0EB9A6E71B18" Type="119" Title="$Resources:core,WikiWebLibPages;" Url="$Resources:core,WikiWebLibPages_Folder;" />
```

Comment: I need to change Id of the feature that activates this ListDefinition or add this FeatureId attribute to my Schema.xml of the ListDef?

Comment: Have a look at this MSDN article: [Creating SharePoint 2010 List Definitions in Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg276355.aspx)

Comment: Nice article but it doesn't help me at all.

Comment: In your elements.xml, in the line where you changed the template type, change the feature id if it exists.

Comment: There is an [existing post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21968/custom-list-definition-fields-in-elements-xml-and-schema-xml) around adding fields (columns) to a custom list in elements.xml.

Comment: My problem is to make this ListDefinition capable of creating proper Wiki Pages Libratry instances, not adding fields to a custom lists.
(adding FeatureId to ListDef elements.xml does nothing, and changing it in elements.xml of instance make the project un-deployable ;)